# SSH ClientAliveCountMax & ClientAliveInterval not working

Tags: ssh, openssh, sshd

I changed the following SSH config (and rebooted the SSH, or even rebooted the server):

```
ClientAliveCountMax 120
ClientAliveInterval 720
LoginGraceTime 300
```

Problem is that the parameter "LoginGraceTime" takes effect, I change it and it works. However the other 2 are not working. The server kicks out me after few minutes (4-5 minutes, as was before). If I comment them and restart SSH does not work, it continues kicking out me.

Is there any other parameter interfering with these 2?

Comment: Is there a possibility that the server terminates inactive shell sessions using some means that is unrelated to SSH? It is unclear what you actually mean by "kicks out". It could mean that the SSH connection is terminated, but it could also mean that the shell session is terminated.

Comment: Try running the `sshd` server as a regular user on a non-privileged port with debugging turned on: `/usr/sbin/sshd -ddd -h ~/.ssh/id_rsa -p 2222 -o PidFile=none`, then connect to it with `ssh -p 2222 user_sshd_was_started_as@host`, and add the (edited) debugging output of `sshd` to your question if that's also kicking you out after 4-5 minutes (sshd will still use `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` when started like that).